# Data is coming from Server to Client page, but not Displaying in Angular Project with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm running an Angular Project with MVC. I want to display the data in a grid as shown below. Now the problem is I'm getting the data in Console window as shown in below image. Project is tried with the help of this [pluralsight tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=mvc-applications-add-angular&author=paul-sheriff&name=406ce73b-752e-4fb4-81f1-527519e10677&clip=1&mode=live)

[image]

But it is not displaying. What may be the reason?..Thanks in Advance for your help..
[image]

**product.service.ts**

```
private url = "/api/ProductAPI";
constructor(private http: Http) {    }

getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(this.ExtractData).catch(this.handleErrors);
}  
private ExtractData(res: Response)
{
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.getProducts();
}
products: Product[] = [];
private getProducts()
{
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((products) => this.products = products, errors => this.handleErrors(errors));

}
```

**product-list.component.html**

```
    <div class="row"
      *ngIf="products && products.length">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered ">
<thead>
    <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Introduction Date</td>
        <td>Url</td>
        <td class="text-right">Price</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr 
                        *ngFor ="let product of products">
                        <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.introductionDate | date}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.url}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.price |currency:'USD':true }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code from where you are calling `getProducts`

Comment: could you add the result of a console.log in the component subscribe callback and the template of your component ?

Comment: Added @VivekDoshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename your variables for test, like this:

```
<tr *ngFor ="let product of products">
    <td>{{product.ProductName}}</td>
    <td>{{product.IntroductionDate | date}}</td>
    <td>{{product.Url}}</td>
    <td>{{product.Price |currency:'USD':true }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Solved...sorry for the simple mistake

Comment: Make sure you change your interface names.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to your server returning the properties as `PascalCase` and your interface properties are `camelCase`.

Change your interface properties to match the returned JSON as `PascalCase` or change your server to return `camelCase` properties

e.g.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
  {
      services.AddMvc()
                  .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                  {
                      options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                          new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                  });
  }
```